# Find regular expression in a file matching a given value

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I have some basic knowledge on using regular expressions with grep (bash).
But I want to use regular expressions the other way around.

For example I have a file containing the following entries:

```
line_one=[0-3]
line_two=[4-6]
line_three=[7-9]
```

Now I want to use bash to figure out to which line a particular number matches.
For example:

```
grep 8 file
```

should return:

```
line_three=[7-9]
```

Note: I am aware that the example of "grep 8 file" doesn't make sense, but I hope it helps to understand what I am trying to achieve.

Thanks for you help,
Marcel

Comment: Eh? If your regex is `line_three=[7-9]`, then it does not match `8`, since `8` does not contain `line_three=`. Do you mean the part after `=` is supposed to be a regex, is that a mistake in your example, or am I misunderstanding what you wrote in your question?

Comment: Yes, the part after = is the regex
In that case 8 matches [7-9]

Comment: Note: It is nor important to get the [7-9] back in the result.

I only need to know the string before the =-sign

Comment: Do I understand this right: you have a file with regexes after the `=` sign, and for a given string (`8` in the example), you want the lines for which the regex matches that string?

Comment: @Radje, can you clarify whether you want to match a numeric range, specifically and only, or whether you want this to work with regexes in general?

Comment: @Radje, ...to be clear, if what you want is only numeric ranges, this would mean a substantially different question -- for example, it's rather complicated to specify the numeric range 46-53 as a regex. OTOH, I'd argue that you'd need to ask a different/separate question, if that were your real intent, as this one was explicitly asked (and has been answered by multiple folks honoring that request) about regexes.

Answer (score 2):

As others haven pointed out, `awk` is the right tool for this:

`awk -F'=' '8~$2{print $0;}' file`

... and if you want this tool to feel more like grep, a quick bash wrapper:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -F'=' -v seek_value="$1" 'seek_value~$2{print $0;}' "$2"
```

Which would run like:

```
./not_exactly_grep.sh 8 file
line_three=[7-9]
```

Comment: Quote your values -- `-v seek_value="$1"`, and `"$2"`. Otherwise, IMHO this is the best awk-based answer here.

Comment: @dawg - whys that? Just tested it on "line_four=[7-9][123]" and that works just fine

Comment: Sure, but that also isn't a valid input for the grep-like scenario OP is trying to find an inverse-solution to

Comment: @dawg, ...did the OP say they want a numeric range? They specify a "regular expression" in the question, quite repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

My first impression is that this is not a task for grep, maybe for awk.

Trying to do things with grep I only see this:

```
for line in $(cat file); do echo 8 | grep "${line#*=}" && echo "${line%=*}" ; done
```

Using while for file reading (following comments):

```
while IFS= read -r line; do echo 8 | grep "${line#*=}" && echo "${line%=*}" ; done < file
```

Comment: `${line#*=*}` will remove the whole line, i.e., expand to the empty string – you probably just want `${line#*=}`.

Comment: [Don't Read Lines With For](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) -- the current code will behave badly with spaces in your values. See also [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001). And more quotes -- you'll have bugs with spaces or glob characters without them.

Comment: I know it, if needed just an " could do the job. I'll edit to cover your comments.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in native bash using the syntax `[[ $value =~ $regex ]]` to test:

```
find_regex_matching() {
  local value=$1
  while IFS= read -r line; do         # read from input line-by-line
    [[ $line = *=* ]] || continue     # skip lines not containing an =
    regex=${line#*=}                  # prune everything before the = for the regex
    if [[ $value =~ $regex ]]; then   # test whether we match...
      printf '%s\n' "$line"           # ...and print if we do.
    fi
  done
}
```

...used as:

```
find_regex_matching 8 <file
```

...or, to test it with your sample input inline:

```
find_regex_matching 8 <<'EOF'
line_one=[0-3]
line_two=[4-6]
line_three=[7-9]
EOF
```

...which properly emits:

```
line_three=[7-9]
```

---

You could replace `printf '%s\n' "$line"` with `printf '%s\n' "${line%%=*}"` to print only the key (contents before the `=`), if so inclined. See [the bash-hackers page on parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) for a rundown on the syntax involved.

Answer (score 0):

This is not built-in functionality of `grep`, but it's easy to do with `awk`, with a change in syntax:

```
/[0-3]/ { print "line one" }
/[4-6]/ { print "line two" }
/[7-9]/ { print "line three" }
```

If you really need to, you could programmatically change your input file to this syntax, if it doesn't contain any characters that need escaping (mainly `/` in the regex or `"` in the string):

```
sed -e 's@\(.*\)=\(.*\)@/\2/ { print "\1" }@'
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you are looking for a range that includes some value.

You can do this in `gawk`:

```
$ cat /tmp/file
line_one=[0-3]
line_two=[4-6]
line_three=[7-9]

$ awk  -v n=8 'match($0, /([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/, a){ if (a[1]<n && a[2]>n) print $0 }' /tmp/file
line_three=[7-9]
```

Since the digits are being treated as numbers (vs a regex) it supports larger ranges:

```
$ cat /tmp/file
line_one=[0-3]
line_two=[4-6]
line_three=[75-95]
line_four=[55-105]

$ awk  -v n=92 'match($0, /([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/, a){ if (a[1]<n && a[2]>n) print $0 }' /tmp/file
line_three=[75-95]
line_four=[55-105]
```

---

If you are just looking to interpret the right hand side of the `=` as a regex, you can do:

```
$ awk  -F= -v tgt=8 'tgt~$2' /tmp/file
```

Comment: The OP very explicitly asked about regexes. If they *wanted* to ask about numeric ranges, that should be a different question.

Answer (score 0):

You would like to do something like

```
grep -Ef <(cut -d= -f2 file) <(echo 8)
```

This wil grep what you want but will not display where.
With grep you can show some message:

```
echo "8" | sed -n '/[7-9]/ s/.*/Found it in line_three/p'
```

Now you would like to transfer your regexp file into such commands:

```
sed 's#\(.*\)=\(.*\)#/\2/ s/.*/Found at \1/p#' file
```

Store these commands in a virtual command file and you will have

```
echo "8" | sed -nf <(sed 's#\(.*\)=\(.*\)#/\2/ s/.*/Found at \1/p#' file)
```